# Role of ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring

Besides loading optional root applicationContext for a web application what is the role of `ContextLoaderListener`?

In Spring docs API it says
Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root `WebApplicationContext`.
From some other discussions I found that `ServletContextListener` creates a `WebApplicationContext` and `WebApplicationContext` provides access to the `ServletContext` via `ServletContextAware` beans and the `getServletContext` method.Otherwise it would need to be created manually.

But `ContextLoaderListener` is not mandatory. So if don't use `ContextLoaderListener` do we need to create `WebApplicationContext` manually?

Answer (score 1):

The WebApplicationContext is bound in the ServletContext and is defined in your web.xml like:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/my-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If you dont configure it with a custom config file like previous (my-context.xml) and you omit this entry in your web.xml, Spring DispatcherServlet search and loads its configuration file using 
 <servlet_name>-servlet.xml.  
In the my-context.xml like above (or in a <servlet_name>-servlet.xml) there could be defined Web Components as:

- Controllers
- ViewResolvers
- LocaleResolvers
- ThemeResolvers

If you want to have access to middle tier components (from Multi Web Components) like

- DAO
- Entity
- Service

you need a parent Context. Therefore you could define in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>    
        /WEB-INF/config/application-context-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/config/application-context-dao.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

ContextLoaderListener creates a root web-application-context for the web-application and puts it in the ServletContext of the root Application. DispatcherServlet creates its own WebApplicationContext and the handlers, controllers, view-resolvers etc. are managed by this WebApplicationContext.